# Running a Spark application on a SuperComputer

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, supercomputers

I have some question about YARN?

How can i run my jar file on YARN ?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: When running with
>   master 'yarn-cluster' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be
>   set in the environment.

Should i copy Spark on every node in this SuperComputer?

> in this SuperComputer, all nodes are interconnected, and it has
>   own Architecture.

is there any one who could run a Spark application on a SuperComputer?

Comment: what type of file system does your super computer have?  local or shared?

Comment: it has shared file system.

Comment: Then you only need to have it put in one place.  If you ssh to the different nodes in the cluster, you should be able to see the hadoop installation.  I believe your issue is that HADOOP_CONF_DIR needs to be set in the .bashrc of the user you are running the jar as.  I am assuming that you are running some version of Linux.  What is your OS?